# Convex function and second devirative

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

I would like to ask a question about the condition of a convex function.

We know that a function $f(x)$ is convex if and only if $f''(x) \geq 0$.

But what if a function has more than one variable? For example $f(x,y,z)=x^2 - yz$.

Is this correct:

Since $f''(x,y,z)= 2 + 0 + 0 \geq 0$,

the function $f(x,y,z)$ is convex.

Comment: No @Dylan this is not correct. You need to go for multi-variable calculus.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot differentiate $f$ just like that beacause $f$ has three variables.

I guess you're not familiar with multivariate calculus but if you want to know if $f$ is convex, a way to do it is to compute the hessian matrix and see if it's positive semi-definite at every point.

Answer (score 2):

When the function is of more than one variable (called multi-variate), what you look for is called the Hessian of the function at that point [Read about how to calculate Hessian here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix). The Hessian should be positive semi-definite in order for the function to be convex.

Hessian is double derivative of the function w.r.t a vector at a given point.
Being positive semi-definite implies that, for any vector x in domain of $f$

$$
x^T H x \geq 0 
$$

Where $H$ is the Hessian matrix.